# diff to show only the additions in a changed file

Tags: grep, git, diff

Normally `diff` and `git diff` show both the original and the modified line with `-` and `+` respectively. Is there any way, I can filter only to see the modified line? This would reduce the number of lines to read by a factor of 2 instantly.

I was assuming

```
git diff test.yml | grep '^+' | less -R
```

and

```
git diff test.yml | egrep '^+' | less -R
```

to have the same result. ie they would show any new additions in a file. However `egrep` shows me the entire file. Why is that so?

With the above method anyways, I lose the color. Is there any way to retain the color?

Comment: So you don't care whether it's a new line or a replaced line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `--word-diff` to condense the `+` and `-` lines together with the changes highlighted using red/green text and stop using grep all together.

[image]

You can combine this with `-U0` to remove all context around the diffs if you really want to condense it down further.

[image]

This approch is better than using grep as you don't lose output, you can tell when a line was added or simply changed and you don't completely lose removals while still condensing the output down into something that is easy to read.

The answer to the question regarding egrep is already answered by @Stephen Kitt [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392195/119007)

Comment: word-diff and U# is indeed cool ! It immediately reduces the length of  the diff by a factor of 2 making it read quicker. If you cite the answers form @Stephen Kitt with respect to egrep, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Your syntax highlighting is really impressive, but next time please use copy-paste...

Comment: Problem with copy paste in this example is it loses all of the syntax highlighting which is important to show the actual diff - otherwise it makes no sense.

Answer (score 5):

`egrep` uses extended regular expressions, so

```
egrep '^+'
```

matches one or more beginnings of lines (`+` is a special character here), which is undefined and can result in an error or a variety of behaviours depending on the `egrep` implementation.

To match the “+” character you need to escape it:

```
egrep '^\+'
```

To see colours, you need to force `git` to output them; by default it disables them when piping:

```
git diff --color
```

To filter this you need to take the escape codes used for colours into account:

```
git diff --color ... | egrep '^.[[[:digit:]]+m\+' | less -R
```

Comment: I get `egrep: repetition-operator operand invalid` with macOS version of grep and zsh. `egrep "^\+"` worked for me

Comment: `^` is used for history when at the start of the line like in csh, `^` is also an extendedglob operator, but here, their error is from `egrep`. `grep -E '^+'` produces undefined results in the POSIX specification, some grep implementations treat it as an error, some as one or more of *nothing* at the beginning of the line, some could try and interpret it as one or more beginning of the subject, whatever that means, or as `+` at the beginning of the subject...

Comment: Ah yes of course, since the error starts with `egrep:` anyway it has to come from `egrep`…

Comment: See also `egrep '^[+]'` as an alternative way to escape the `+`.

Answer (score 4):

Can also be done with `grep` alone.

```
$ grep -xvFf filea.txt fileb.txt
```

This takes the lines from one file and looks for them in the other, printing out only ones which don't match exactly.

Answer (score 3):

While using `grep` works, you can use a flag to achieve similar and possibly a more succinct result.

---

#### `git diff`

You can adjust the amount of context `git diff` provides with the `-U` flag. From `man git-diff`:

```
   -U<n>, --unified=<n>
       Generate diffs with <n> lines of context instead of the usual three. Implies -p.
```

`git diff -U0` will produce minimal/simple output with no context for each change.

---

#### `diff`

The same flag applies to `diff`:

```
   -u  -U NUM  --unified[=NUM]
          Output NUM (default 3) lines of unified context.
```

Example (`diff -U0` would work the same way):

```
$ diff -U0 <(echo -e "abc123\ndef345") <(echo -e "abc123\nghi678")
--- /dev/fd/63  2017-09-14 09:18:01.000000000 -0400
+++ /dev/fd/62  2017-09-14 09:18:01.000000000 -0400
@@ -2 +2 @@
-def345
+ghi678
```

Answer (score 1):

> However `egrep` shows me the entire file. Why is that so?

Because `egrep` uses extended regular expressions, so `egrep ^+` matches the beginning of each line one or more times (i.e. it matches all lines).  Use `egrep ^\+` to match only lines starting with `+`.

> With the above method anyways, I lose the color. Is there any way to retain the color?

Yes, add option `--color=always`:

```
git diff --color=always | less -R
```

Answer (score 0):

The following shows a `git diff` only showing modified lines while preserving color.

`git diff file1.txt file2.txt --word-diff --color=always | grep -P '\+|\-' --color=never`